# Fitting CDF in R to Discrete Data

Tags: r, frequency, curve-fitting

I have a series of values, say $25, $50, $75, etc. I also have a frequency of each of these values (say .6, .3, and .1) respectively. How would I fit a continuous CDF to this data without having to make a data set showing $25 6 times, $50 3 times, and $75 1 time. Is there to fit a curve by the mle process which shows cumulative frequency vs. severity?

I have all my data in Excel. In total, it would take around 1 million data points to summarize the frequency in one data column. This just takes up way too much excel data.

I haven't been able to find any code. I'm trying to use fitdist or something of the sort to use the MLE process to fit the CDF.

For reasons above, I haven't had any results.

Comment: try the `ecdf()` function.

Comment: Let's say I have X <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50) and P <- c(.2, .3, .3, .1, .1). How would I use ecdf to fit a continuous probability distribution (such as gamma, Weibull, etc.) to this data set?

Comment: Think about using ‘cumsum()’

Comment: If you are thinking about common parametric distributions, such as normal, I think you can easily just ignore the fact that your data is discrete and just use maximum likelihood for a continuous distribution.  However, you should also think why do you want to use a model that is clearly a wrong representation of your data.